# Advantages of using timeSeries over container resource

Tags: onem2m

The timeSeries resource represents a container for data instances and timeSeriesInstance resource represents a data instance in the  resource.

The main difference from container and contentInstance is to keep the time information with data and to be able to detect the missing data.

Is there any other advantage which can be achieved using timeSeries and timeSeriesInstance resource instead of container and contentInstance resources?

Does it also help in saving data redundancy e.g. if my one application instance is sending data every 30 seconds so in a day 24*120 contentInstance will be created.

If timeSeries and timeSeriesInstance resources are being used then will the same number of timeSeriesInstance be created in a day (i.e. 24*120) for the above case?

Also, is there any specific purpose for keeping contentInfo attribute in timeSeries instead of timeSeriesInstance (like we have contentInfo in contentInstance resource)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of differences between the <container> and <timeSeries> resource types.

A <container> resource may contain an arbitrary number of <contentInstance> resources as well as <flexContainer> and (sub) <container> resources as child resources. The advantage of this is that a <container> can be further structured to represent more complex data types.

This is also the reason why the *contentInfo* attribute cannot be part of the <container> resource, because the type of the content can just be mixed, or the <container> resource my not have direct <contentInstance> resources at all.

A <timeSeries> resource can only have <timeSeriesInstance> resources as a child resource (except from <subscription>, <oldest>, <latest> etc). It is assumed that all the child <timeSeriesInstance> resources are of the same type, therefore the *contentInfo* is located in the <timeSeries> resource.

<timeSeriesInstance> resources may also have a *sequenceNr* attribute which allows the CSE to check for missing or out-of-sequence data. See, for example, the *missingDataDetect* attribute in the <timeSeries> resource.

For your application (sending and storing data every 30 seconds): It depends on the requirements. Is it important that measurements are transmitted all the time, or when it is important to know when data is missing? Then use <timeSeries> and <timeSeriesInstances>. If your application just sends data when the measurement changes and it is only important to retrieve the latest value, then use <container> and <contentInstance>.

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer when you agree that it answers your question?

Answer (score 2):

Two uses cases for <timeSeries> that seem better to me than using a <container>.

The first use case involves the *dataGenerationTime* attribute.  This allows a sensor to specifically record the time that a sensor value was captured, whereas with a <contentInstance> you have the creation time (you could put the capture time into the *content* attribute, but then that requires additional processing to extract from the *content*).  If you use the *creationtime* attribute of the <contentInstance> there  will be variations in the time based on when the CSE receives the primitive.  When using the <timeSeriesInstance> the variations go away because the CREATE request includes the *dataGenerationTime* attribute.  That makes the data more accurate.

The second use case involves the *missingDataDetect* attribute.  In short, using this, along with the expected *periodicInterval* you can implement a "heartbeat" type functionality for your sensor.  If the sensor does not send a measurement indicating that the door is closed/open every 30 seconds, a notification can be sent indicating that the sensor is malfunctioning or tampered with.

Comment: Yeah..overall that's what I figured out..one to get the actual time and second to get the malfunctioning of sensors.